# Node.js: readline never returns

Tags: node.js, readline

I tried several different versions of node.js but readline.question never seems to execute my callback. Can anybody spot what I may be doing wrong?

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

rl.question('What do you think of node.js? ', function(answer) {
  console.log('Thank you for your valuable feedback:', answer);
  rl.close();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code works perfectly and my problem was due to the fact that I was using `forever`. When using a process manager like `forever`, `pm2`, or `nx` beware that your streams are modified and thus the input may not be received by the underlying process.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * main.js
 */
//
const readline = require('readline');
//
const rl = readline.createInterface({
input: process.stdin,
output:process.stdout
});
//
var question = "What do you think of node.js? \n";
var feedback = "Thank you for your valuable feedback:\n ";
console.log(question);
rl.question('//////////////...ANSWER..//////////////////////\n:',
function(answer){
console.log(feedback, answer);
rl.close();
});
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Your environment should be set up for using Node.js and npm.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////...OUTPUT...////////////////////////////////////////
//$ node main.js
//What do you think of node.js?
//
//////////////...ANSWER...//////////////////////
//: Cool. All APIs of Node.js are asynchronous.
//Thank you for your valuable feedback:
//  Cool. All APIs of Node.js are asynchronous.
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//
```

Comment: Hi BM3, when posting an answer, it is helpful to have a couple sentences explaining what the person did wrong and what you did to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: NodeJS is JavaScript. It uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model. The problem with non-blocking model is that, the callback function can run up to the end without waiting for other critical information that is necessary for the program to function properly. For example, if the program ask for user's input, it should wait for user's response before proceeding to the next step. The programmer is in control of the program flow. He/She should decide when to use asynchronous functions and when to use synchronous functions. The programmer can use console.log("To test line by line output.").